# Why am I not able to route my app? react - react-router - redux-router

Tags: reactjs, react-router, redux

I have a simple `redux/react` app and I am only able to route to the root `/`.  I am using `react 0.14`, `redux 3.0.2`, `react-router 1.0.0-rc-3` and `redux-router1.0.0-rx-3`.  Here is my app:

```jsx
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { Route} from 'react-router';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { ReduxRouter } from 'redux-router';

import store from './store/lcrf.store.js';

import App from './containers/App';
import Test from './containers/Test';

ReactDOM.render((
  <Provider store={store}>
    <ReduxRouter>
        <Route path="/" component={App}>
            <Route path="test" component={Test} />
        </Route>
    </ReduxRouter>
  </Provider>
), document.getElementById('app'));
```

Here is my `App` component:

```jsx
class App extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div>           
                <h1>App Component</h1>
                {this.props.children}
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

My `Test` component is the same thing, without the `this.props.children`.

```jsx
class Test extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <h1>Test</h1>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default Test;
```

I am serving the `index.html` from an `express` server.  Here is that file:

```js
var express = require('express');

var app = express();
var port = 3333;

app.use(express.static('public'));

app.listen(port, error => {
    if(error) {
        console.error(error);
    } else {
        console.info(`Server is listening on port ${port}`);
    }
})
```

My `index.html` is in my `public` directory.

When I go to `/`, I see my `App` component, but I cannot route to my `Test` component.  I have tried `/test` and `#/test`, but it is not working.  What I have configured incorrectly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`express` was not handling my `pushState`.  I don't know the most elegant way to do this, but when I added:

```
app.get('*', function(request, response){
  response.sendfile('./public/index.html');
});
```

to my server, then everything started to work fine.  I would love to hear the correct way to manage this.

Comment: Express doesn't know about pushState (since it can't talk directly to the browser API). Using a wildcard route to serve up your index.html is the standard approach.