# Koa w/client side router

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, koa

Current situation:

frontend: React & React-Router

backend: Koa

```
app.use(mount('/graphql', graphqlHTTP({ schema: schema })));
app.use(mount('/api', api));
app.use(serve(__dirname + '../../public')); //serves static index.html
```

When I click on React Router's < Link > in the browser, every webpages shows.
Whenever I refresh the page or manually enter a link. I get a 'not found' page. There is no server side rendering going here by the way. How do I let React-Router handle routes not specified above, i.e. only on the client?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution (based on the answer above)

```
import router from 'koa-router';
import sendfile from 'koa-sendfile';
//code to initialize router
//...

router.get('*', function* () {
    let stats = yield* sendfile.call(this, pathToIndexHtml));

     if (!this.status) this.throw(404)
})
```

Koa now serves index.html on every route that isn't specified. :)

Comment: What is the root of sendfile? Is it relative to where the server.js is?

Answer (score 3):

The server has to respond with *something* when the page is refreshed; in this case, it needs to respond with `index.html` so that the client-side application can boot, and then React Router can mount the right component based on the URL.

So, server-side, you need to tell Koa to serve `index.html` for *every* URL that doesn't already match any of the other routes.

Comment: here is the example to what @BinaryMuse said http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33062215/why-am-i-not-able-to-route-my-app-react-react-router-redux-router/33062323#33062323

Comment: That's a good example for an Express server; I would post one for Koa but I'm not very familiar with it. :)

Comment: Thanks, I works; I translated the express example to koa.